# What does this statement mean about overriding hashcode and equals?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I have this statement about java equals and hashcode.

> if we were to use such an Integer object for a key in a HashMap, we would not be able to reliably retrieve the associated value

what it means ? why it says 'not reliably' ? I write a test program, it always works.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Integer, Student> map = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();

        map.put(1, new Student("john"));        
        map.put(2, new Student("peter"));

        Student s1 = map.get(1);
        Student s2 = map.get(1);
        Student s3 = map.get(2);
        System.out.println("s1:"+s1+" s2:"+s2+" s3:"+s3);

        System.out.println(s1==s2);
        System.out.println(s1==s3);
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    }   
}

class Student{
    private String name;
    public Student(String name){        
        this.name = name;       
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }   
}
```

Comment: you need to quote more

Comment: such an Integer object? which one???

Comment: Where does this statement come from? What's the full context?

Comment: See my answer. It's a selective quote and incorrect on its own!

Comment: -1 it's a poor question because you ignore over half the relevant paragraph and don't provide a link.

Comment: It was ok to be confused by the wording of the paragraph and ask the question. Less OK to leave out the URL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have misunderstood! Read the **whole** paragraph:

> What would happen **if Integer did not** override equals() and hashCode()?
>   Nothing, if we never used an Integer as a key in a HashMap or other
>   hash-based collection. However, if we were to use such an Integer
>   object for a key in a HashMap, we would not be able to reliably
>   retrieve the associated value, unless we used the exact same Integer
>   instance in the get() call as we did in the put() call.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

This is saying that the `Integer` class must have a `hashCode()` method and `equals()` in order to work. It **does** have those methods, so it's fine. It will work.

The example was saying that references to objects that store values should not be compared because two `Integers` with the same integer value may actually be different objects.

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
Integer y = new Integer(5);
```

`x.equals(y)` is always true. `x == y` is not always true (but can be sometimes). The rules change for different ranges of value. Never rely on `==` for any object references unless you are completely sure you know what you are doing.

Also note that you are passing `int` arguments (primitive types) not `Integers` (references to objects) but your collection's generic type is `Integer`. This means there is also boxing to throw into the equation!

Comment: It's an innocent enough question.

Answer (score 2):

The [full context of the quote](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html):

> What would happen if Integer did not override equals() and hashCode()?
>   Nothing, if we never used an Integer as a key in a HashMap or other
>   hash-based collection. However, if we were to use such an Integer
>   object for a key in a HashMap, we would not be able to reliably
>   retrieve the associated value, unless we used the exact same Integer
>   instance in the get() call as we did in the put() call.

The default equality test in Java is a strict instance equality test (i.e. `var1` and `var2` are equal if and only if `var1` and `var2` point to the same object in memory). However, if you use an `Integer` as a key into a `Map`, you probably want the actual *number that it represents* to be the key (not the `Integer` instance itself), which is incompatible with this strict equality test. So, `Integer` must override `hashCode` and `equals` to make this work (which it does).

Comment: As a note: Integer does override hashCode and equals correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some information.

What you are talking about is the specific `.hashcode()` and `.equals()` contract. They need to follow certain properties for them to be correct, and thus usable by other classes that rely on them (Java Collections make extensive usage of `.hashcode()` and `.equals()`).

It's well explained here: http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html.

The book "Effective Java" also has very good hints about these methods.